# SQL query to sort data while insert , first numbers then alphabets an last symbols

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting trouble to write SQL sort Query, 
I have table as follows

[image]

And I want to sort above data as, First should number and then alphabets and last special symbols like following table.

First numbers should sort like 1,2,3,11,22,33
then Alphabets should sort like a ,b,c,..z 
and then symbols,
like following table

[image]

I have tried many ways but still not getting correct way, please help me to write query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE WHEN` on the `ORDER BY` to create some groups:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN LEFT(FilterParameterValue, 1) LIKE '[0-9]' OR LEFT(FilterParameterValue, 2) LIKE '-[0-9]' OR LEFT(FilterParameterValue, 2) LIKE '+[0-9]' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC, -- group for numbers
  CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(FilterParameterValue) = 1 THEN CAST(FilterParameterValue AS MONEY) ELSE NULL END ASC, -- order the numeric values
  CASE WHEN LEFT(FilterParameterValue, 1) LIKE '[A-Za-z]' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC, -- group for chars from A to Z (capital / non capital)
  colName
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fcf767485d78890084e00786922ec022)

Comment: expected result is getting wrong, it is not sorting numbers like 1 2,11, 22 , your query showing result as 1,11,2,22

Comment: this works fine as expected , but getting exception on special character , error is - Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '$' to data type int.

Comment: it is  throwing exception on when we use '$'

Comment: Already updated use `MONEY` instead of `INT` so you can also sort decimal numbers (see demo)

Answer (score 0):

Try using regex in order by clause.. For ex

ORDER BY IF(FilterParameterValue RLIKE '^[a-z]', 1, 2), FilterParameterValue

Answer (score 0):

You can try to cast your **Column** to **Numeric Type** then ordered

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY TRY_CAST(Column_Name as Type)
```